# I need help with extracting x and y from this formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

this is my first time posting, I couldn't do this by myself (its way out of my league), I need to extract x and y from the formula here:

$$ vpa = 0.6112 \times \mathit e ^ \left(\frac{18.678-\mathit x}{234.5} \times x \over {x + 257.14}\right)\times y $$

that superscript is:

$$ {{18.678 - x \over 234.5}  \times x} \over x+ 257.14 $$

Is it even possible? Thank you in advance, i appreciate this much!

Comment: Do you mean simultaneously ? This is not possible.

Comment: Sorry but getting $y$ is immediate, you should not even be asking. For $x$ take the logarithm and rewrite as a quadratic equation.

Comment: i understand that you get it, but i dont, and i couldnt do it by myself, thats why i asked here... well, ill just find some other place to ask... tnx for the insight tough...

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by $0.6112y$ and take the $\log$.  Define $z=\log \frac{vpa}{0.6112y}$.  Then you have
$$z={{{18.678 - x \over 234.5}  \times x} \over x+ 257.14}\\
(x+257.14)z\cdot234.5=(18.678-x)x=18.678x-x^2$$
Which is a quadratic you can feed to the formula to get $x$ in terms of $z$.  You can substitute back in to get it in terms of $y$

Comment: wow, thank you mate! this is exactly what i needed! thanks again for your effort... i cant upvote you cause im new here tough... <3